# How to "wait" for a sync method to complete

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

I am making a context menu, and in this menu, I am using a key for translation.
I would like to "wait" for this method to finish, before moving on, and display the context menu on my page **only** when I am certain, that the translation files have already been loaded.

So, here is what I have tried.

```
contextMenuContent: {
  [key: string]: ContextMenuEntries;
};

constructor(private translationService: TranslationService) {
}

async ngOnInit() {
  this.contextMenuContent = await this.makeContextMenuEntries();
}

async makeContextMenuEntries() {
  return {
    editContextMenuEntry: {
      icon: 'edit',
      text: this.t('edit_contacts'),
      action: () => {}
    }
  };
}

t<T = string>(key: string, param?: object): T {
  return this.translationService.translate(`${TRANSLATION_KEY}.${key}`, param);
}
```

It is working, but I am looking for a better solution, and I really want to avoid marking ngOnInit as async. How can I improve my code?

Comment: Your function `t` returns a promise or a simple string? Because if it's a simple string, I don't understand why it should be async.

Comment: Yes, it returns a string, but I would like to make sure that this string is there when the context menu gets displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, angular will wait for all the **SYNC** functions in `ngOnInit` to finish.

You can do a quick demonstration by running:

```
ngOnInit(){
    let a = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      a += i.toString();
    }
}
```

You will see that the component will be displayed only after a few seconds, the time for the functions in `ngOnInit` to finish.

So in your case, if the translation doesn't exist, there aren't too many solutions:

- Display nothing because the translation service will never get the solution. No async and await are required because all are SYNC.

  ```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.contextMenuContent = this.makeContextMenuEntries();
  }

    makeContextMenuEntries() {
     return {
       editContextMenuEntry: {
         icon: 'edit',
         text: this.t('edit_contacts'),
         action: () => {}
       }
     };
  }

  t<T = string>(key: string, param?: object): T {
     return this.translationService.translate(`${TRANSLATION_KEY}.${key}`, param);
  }
  ```
- Change your `translate` method for a promise so it would wait the translation in an async way.